# Passing parameters with AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Regarding to the topic, as google/android documentations says:

```
// Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
// Progress, the type of the progress units published during the background
// computation.
// Result, the type of the result of the background computation.
```

I've used several times AsyncTask but always have some doubts (in general working with multithreading:) how to pass/return parameters with it. I'm familiar with AsyncTask documentation but would like to know If the way I pass context/intent parameters is the proper way or should I do this with `<Params, Progress, Result>`.. :

```
class CameraStarterTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private Context context;
    private Intent intent;

    public void CameraStarter(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;
        this.intent = intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's all the same.  You can't even execute the same AsyncTask instance more than once at the same time, so it really makes no difference which method you use to pass parameters.

Comment: Ok, I've used another approach for this:   mHandler.postDelayed(new CameraStarter(context, intent), 7000);

Answer (score 0):

That's your decision how to do it. AsyncTask just gives you a nice generic way of passing arguments through different Thread instances (one background Thread and the UI Thread). You can even do this stuff on your own, if you think it suits you better.

Like starting a background new Thread and inside its Runnable post another Runnable on a UI element/your Activity/Handler etc.

You see it's ok to use it your way. Just make sure you thought everything through when config changes occur, but you' prob know this stuff or find enough tutorials for that.